# Do clan members ever get matched against each other in standard Arena battles?

Tags: clash-royale

When playing a standard arena battle in Clash Royale (not a "friendly" or "tournament" battle), is it possible (however remotely) for two members of the exact same clan to end up being matched together to battle each other?

Follow-up question: same question as above, but for a "challenge" battle.

Answer (score 1):

*Ladder:* I would say no, as the wintraders back in the day made different clans to fight their own accounts (all the nova clans and all that). If one could battle their clanmates, this probably would not have happened.

*Challenges:* We don't know either. The link I posted was removed after I read it over and realized they were in different clans.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in normal arena battles, but the chance is so small to find exactly your friend, even if he had the exact same trophy count, that you could say that the chance is 0%, even if you search for an opponent in the exact same moment. I'm not sure if this works even in challenge matches, but it's probably the same thing.

Comment: Is there evidence of this happening?

Comment: @JoshDM Sadly, I don't have any evidence, and it never happened to me, but There are many posts that I have read of this on social webs that say that it is possible, and other things like this. And I was also thinking: why should Supercell restrict theese battles?

Answer (score 0):

According to sirtag's video, you can.

Comment: Can you add a time stamp where he explains this? It's an 18 minute video with most of the info being about his deck.

Comment: @XtremeSteel - please.identify the timestamp in the video.

Comment: But that's not standard arena battles

Answer (score 0):

Ladder : You can, but the chance is so rare that it probably wouldn't happen.

Challenges: More likely to happen as less people tend to play challenges.